# table cell height is bigger than it's width (but set the same number for both)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to put a grid (table) on a div using Javascript. The div has a width of 600px and a height of 400px. Every cell of the table is 20x20px. But the height of cells is bigger than their width. Why's that? And how to fix that?

```js
var htmlElements = "";

for (var r = 0; r < 20; r++) {
  htmlElements += '<tr class="tRow">';

  for (var c = 0; c < 30; c++) {
    htmlElements += '<td class="tCell"></td>';
  }

  htmlElements += '</tr>'

}


var theTable = document.getElementById("tab");
theTable.innerHTML = htmlElements;
```

```css
#workspace {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -300px;
  margin-top: -200px;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0;
}

td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="workspace">
  <table id="tab">

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I run your script and the cells appear to be in a perfect square shape. do they change width/height when you add data into the cells?

Comment: @pravinnavle I won't add any data to the cells. Just change background of every single cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cells are rescaling because you have set a fixed height and width for the container `#workspace`.

In a table, explicit cell widths and heights are always overridden by the table size as a whole.

If you insist on setting a width then ensure the correct calculation is used.

In this case the width is `631px`. *(30 right borders and 1 left)*.

I believe your failed to account for the 1px border in your sum.

```js
var htmlElements = "";

for (var r = 0; r < 20; r++) {
  htmlElements += '<tr class="tRow">';

  for (var c = 0; c < 30; c++) {
    htmlElements += '<td class="tCell"></td>';
  }

  htmlElements += '</tr>'

}


var theTable = document.getElementById("tab");
theTable.innerHTML = htmlElements;
```

```css
#workspace {
  position: absolute;
  width: 631px;
  height: 421px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -300px;
  margin-top: -200px;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0;
}

td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="workspace">
  <table id="tab">

  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to your cells:

> **border-box** The width and height properties include the content, padding, and border, but do not include the margin. Note that padding
>   and border will be inside of the box.

```js
var htmlElements = "";

for (var r = 0; r < 20; r++) {
  htmlElements += '<tr class="tRow">';

  for (var c = 0; c < 30; c++) {
    htmlElements += '<td class="tCell"></td>';
  }

  htmlElements += '</tr>'

}


var theTable = document.getElementById("tab");
theTable.innerHTML = htmlElements;
```

```css
#workspace {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -300px;
  margin-top: -200px;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="workspace">
  <table id="tab">

  </table>
</div>
```